# C++ Eclipse use libraries

Tags: c++, eclipse, curl, libraries

I am currently encountering a few errors with Eclipse c++. I am a complete newbie to c++ and because I knew Eclipse from java I thought it might be ok. Now to the issue:

I want to use the curl library, but I have no idea how to include it correct. Everywhere around the internet I found that I have to go to the compiler settings, include the library there, go to the linker settings and include it there as well. Now the linker has 2 different panels, one for Libraries (-l) and one for Library paths (-L).

I have downloaded the curl library to this directory:
`C:\Users\Hannes\Desktop\eclipseC\curl-7.45.0`

How do I have to include the Library correctly now?

Here is the error:

> g++ "-LC:\Users\Hannes\Desktop\eclipseC\curl-7.45.0\include\curl" -o HelloWorld.exe HelloWorld.o -lcurl 
>   c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcurl

In the editor the automatic completion for curl methods **does** work.

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

EDIT: Removing `\include\curl` from the Library path (-L) didn't work as well.

Comment: Problems with Eclipse?  Shirley not....

Answer (score 0):

You have included what looks to be an include path not the library path.  Is there a /lib directory under the curl path?
The c/c++ includes should be the path to the header files for curl, the linker path should be to the libraries not the headers, so .a and .dll files normally (normally under a /lib directory).

Comment: Yes there is a /lib directory in "curl-7.45.0". I tried to add that to the linker so it shows "C:\Users\Hannes\Desktop\eclipseC\curl-7.45.0\lib", but I still get the same error: "cannot find -lcurl"

Comment: Is there anything in the /lib directory?  If you have the c/c++ includes included and that library path correct it should find it.  I take it the curl you have has been built so the libraries are there?

Comment: I've downloaded it myself now and there are no libraries there, it needs to be compiled, or get some pre-compiled libraries for your system.

Comment: There are a lot of .h files in the /lib directory, but no .a or .dll files.

I couldn't find any precompiled curl libraries, how do I compile them myself.

Comment: I'd look for a guide on building it or look to get someone else's pre-built stuff.  It's a popular library, in fact there is some pre-built stuff on the download page if you scroll down.